# Angular 4 - handle two events at the same time

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to handle a click event + CTRL keypress event in the same function in my component.ts file, but I don't seem to find a solution anywhere. I've tried:

```
@HostListener("click")
    onDropdownItemClick( evt: keyboardEvent) {
        console.log(evt.keyCode);
    }
```

but it just returns "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined"

I've also tried this too:

```
@Component({
        selector: '....',
        templateUrl: '....',
        host: {
            '(window:keydown)': 'findKey($event)',
            '(window:mousedown)': 'findKey($event)'
        }
   });

findKey(event) {
         if(event.ctrlKey && event.which === 1){
               console.log("CTRL + mouse-click");
        }
    }
```

But it's not working either. Anyone have suggestions on how to catch both events at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `MouseEvent` event provides a `ctrlKey` property that allows to read the state of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key state when the click happened

```
@HostListener("click", ['$event'])
onDropdownItemClick( evt: MouseEvent) {
  console.log('clicked - with ctrl pressed:', evt.ctrlKey);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey

<strike>Just store the status of the control key in a field and read it in the click event:</strike>

```
ctrlDown = false;

@HostListener('window:keydown.ctrl')
onCtrlDown() {this.ctrlDown = true; }

@HostListener('window:keydown.ctrl')
onCtrlUp() {this.ctrlDown = false; }

@HostListener("click")
onDropdownItemClick( evt: keyboardEvent) {
  console.log('clicked - with ctrl pressed:', this.ctrlDown);
}
```

If above doesn't work please try

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
onCtrlDown(event) {this.ctrlDown = event.ctrlKey; }

@HostListener('window:keydown')
onCtrlUp() {this.ctrlDown = false; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm getting this error on the @HostBinding: "TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target." Any idea why that is?

Comment: Sorry, the `['$event']` things weren't necessary but I forgot to remove them. If you want to use them you would need to add a parameter to the function signature like `onCtrlDown(e)`.

Comment: @yurzui thanks, I'm getting really sloppy :-/ Thanks for the fixes!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but no matter if ctrl is pressed or not - I'm getting false in the console..

Comment: I fixed another mistake (sorry :-/ ) in my original code and added another variant worth trying.

Comment: There is a simpler answer. Updated again.

Comment: Or like this https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7ce9e06daba64d762d3e2e7cdee25d7226fb88e9/aio/src/app/app.component.ts#L236

Comment: @yurzui embarrassing :D. Yup, that's a nice one.